# InvoiceParser: errors with uptraing new version after activating invoice_type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

we are using gcloud document ai to parse invoices and we recently enabled the invoice type feature and relabeled all documents with the labeling feature. so that all invoices will have an `invocie_type`, however when we try to uptrain we get the following error:

```json
{
    "code": 3,
    "message": "Invalid document.",
    "details": [
    {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "INVALID_DOCUMENT",
        "domain": "documentai.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
        "document": "gs://documentai-dataset/training/invoice_correction_102242.pdf",
        "annotation_name": "invoice_type",
        "num_fields_needed": "1",
        "field_name": "entities.text_anchor.text_segments",
        "num_fields": "0"
        }
    }
    ]
},
```

the error happens for a lot of documents, but not for all documents. is there a reason why it happens?

we actually relabeled all documents and the `invoice_type` will be set by classification, so it looks like that:

```json
{
    "id": "a47c19621d45f83d",
    "normalizedValue": {
        "text": "invoice_statement"
    },
    "type": "invoice_type"
}
```

and all documents that print the error actually have the value like that?
so it's not even an an `text_anchor` element and its also not possible to set it like a text anchor, does somebody have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

For an [Uptrained Processor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/uptrain-processor), you can't add a general classification type to the Schema unless you can extract it directly from text in the document. For example, if there was actual text in the document that says "Invoice Statement".

You will need to use the [Procurement Splitter & Classifier](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_procurement-document-splitter) or create a [Custom Document Classifier](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_CUSTOM_CLASSIFICATION_PROCESSOR) to perform customized classification of documents.

Comment: ok, so the invoice_type can't be used while doing uptraining, this is really really sad.

Comment: it also looks like the https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_procurement-document-splitter is in a private beta mode or something. is there a way to request access? the formular to request access does not contain a way to request access: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc_6s8jsHLZWWE0aSX0bdmk24XDoPiE_oq5enDApLcp1VKJ-Q/viewform?gxids=7826

Comment: Ok, It's possible the product team isn't allowlisting new users for the Procurement Splitter/Classifier processor at this time. You can try filling it out and specifying in the text fields that you want access to a specific processor not listed.

Alternatively, you can build a custom document classifier to classify your invoice documents. You would then send each document to both processors to get the extraction and the classification separately.